# How can I post a variable from a python file to an html file in Django?

Tags: python, django, post

I am trying to make a face recognition page using PyTorch.
When the face is recognized, I want to go to the next page and print the name of the recognized person.

I wrote the code, but on the next page, None is printed.
In my terminal, "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 532 is printed repeatedly
sometimes "GET /page HTTP/1.1" 200 308 is printed.

That is, I want to output the name and min_dist from the get_frame of camera2.py in the page.html file.

(camera2.py) name, min_dist ---post--->  (page.html) name, min_dist

urls.py

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('detectme', views.detectme, name='detectme'),
    path('page', views.get_post, name='page')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators import gzip
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from detectme.camera2 import FaceDetect

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
              b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@gzip.gzip_page
def detectme(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(FaceDetect()), content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")

def check(request):
    return render(request, "page.html")

def get_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        student = request.POST.get('student')
        pred = request.POST.get('pred')
        data = {
            'name' : student,
            'pred' : pred
        }
        return render(request, 'page.html', data)
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        student = request.POST.get('student')
        pred = request.POST.get('pred')
        data = {
            'name' : student,
            'pred' : pred
        }
        return render(request, 'page.html', data)
```

camera2.py

```
import cv2
import threading
import torch
from facenet_pytorch import MTCNN, InceptionResnetV1
from PIL import Image
import requests

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
mtcnn0 = MTCNN(image_size=240, margin=0, keep_all=False, min_face_size=40)
mtcnn = MTCNN(image_size=240, margin=0, keep_all=True, min_face_size=40)
resnet = InceptionResnetV1(pretrained='vggface2').eval()

class FaceDetect(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.video.read()
        threading.Thread(target=self.update, args=()).start()
    
    def get_frame(self):
        load_data = torch.load('C:\coding\/face2\detectme\data.pt') 
        embedding_list = load_data[0] 
        name_list = load_data[1] 
        url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
        
        while True:
            frame = self.frame
            
            img = Image.fromarray(frame)
            img_cropped_list, prob_list = mtcnn(img, return_prob=True) 
            
            if img_cropped_list is not None:
                boxes, _ = mtcnn.detect(img)
                        
                for i, prob in enumerate(prob_list):
                    if prob>0.90:
                        emb = resnet(img_cropped_list[i].unsqueeze(0)).detach() 
                        
                        dist_list = []
                        
                        for idx, emb_db in enumerate(embedding_list):
                            dist = torch.dist(emb, emb_db).item()
                            dist_list.append(dist)

                        min_dist = min(dist_list)
                        min_dist_idx = dist_list.index(min_dist)
                        name = name_list[min_dist_idx]
                        box = boxes[i] 
                        min_dist = round(min_dist, 3)
                        #original_frame = frame.copy()
                        
                        datas = {
                            'student' : name,
                            'pred' : min_dist
                        }
                        
                        response = requests.post(url, data=datas)
                        
                        if min_dist<0.90:
                            frame = cv2.putText(frame, name+' '+ str(min_dist), (int(box[0]),int(box[1])), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0),1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                        
                        frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (int(box[0]),int(box[1])) , (int(box[2]),int(box[3])), (255,0,0), 2)
                        
            ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
            return jpeg.tobytes()
        
    def update(self):
        while True:
            (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.video.read()
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>video</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">
            <img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/detectme" style="width:400px, height:400px"/>

        </td>
        <td width="50%">
            {% block content%}
            <form name="contents" method="post" action="{% url 'page' %}">
                
                <a href="{% url 'page' %}">post</a>
                </form>

            {{ name }}
            {% endblock %}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> post test </h1>
{% block content %}
{% csrf_token %}
    name : {{ name }} <br>
    pred : {{ pred }}<br>
{%endblock%}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it forward to the next page when a face is detected? I think not. You should use redirect : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect. Whenever a face is detected, use this redirect function to redirect to the next page with the desired parameters. Although I'm not sure if it works when you call it in an 'img' tag's src.

Comment: You're right. Use the `a` tag to move next page. And the reason why I used `img` tag is  I copied the example method of webcam streaming in django